# How to set default value if nothing found in the object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was trying to show list of products and with that i wanted to show the no of sells of that product.

Here `no_of_sell` has `product_id`. The problem is the product which haven't sold they they don't have id in no_of_sell so empty space shows in the view..But i wanted to show the 0 sale for that. How do i show that?

```
$no_of_sells = \DB::table('products')
                    ->leftJoin('buys','products.id','buys.product_id')
                    ->select('products.id',DB::raw('COUNT(buys.product_id) as total_sells'))
                    ->groupBy('products.id')                    
                    ->where('buys.status','=','1')
                    ->get();
```

View Part:

```
@foreach($no_of_sells as $row)
      @if($product->id == $row->id)
         <h3 class="sale">{{$row->total_sells }} sales</h3>
      @endif
@endforeach
```

(here `$product->id` has all the product in the list but $row->id has only the product which is in the buys table.so if it matches it will print the no_of_sell but if it doesn't it should print `0` sell )

Comment: Try something like $totalsales = $row->total_sales; if ($totalsales == null){ $totalsales = 0; }

Answer (score 3):

```
@foreach($no_of_sells as $row)
      @if($product->id == $row->id)
         <h3 class="sale">{{ $row->total_sells or '0' }} sales</h3>
      @endif
@endforeach
```

See more at https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade

Comment: OR is the beste way.

Comment: Problem is the product which have sells shows the the number for 0 sell it shows empty space in view.

Comment: If you vardump the ```$row```, what do you have for a product that has 0 sales ?

Answer (score 3):

```
 <h3 class="sale">{{ ($row->total_sells) ? $row->total_sells : '0' }} sales</h3>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php#102060

Answer (score 1):

Use Following Code :

```
@foreach($no_of_sells as $row)
      @if($product->id == $row->id)
         <h3 class="sale"> @if($row->total_sells > 0) {{$row->total_sells}} @else 0 @endif sales</h3>
      @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try ternary operator like:

```
@foreach($no_of_sells as $row)
      @if($product->id == $row->id)
         <h3 class="sale">{{ ($row->total_sells > 0) ? $row->total_sells : '0'}} sales</h3>
      @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Posted complete code with condition `$row->total_sells > 0`, also my answer not matched with other people given, why down vote?

Comment: There is politics dude. I dont like such people who is downvote someone without any reason.

Comment: Thanks @AnandPandey, but still I need reason from the people who downvote this answer.

Comment: I used your code  
Problem is the product which have sells shows the the number but for 0 sell products it shows empty space in view.